# Http POST to an FTP Server

Tags: http, post, ftp

I want to upload a file to a directory of a ftp server.
I have credentials for the ftp part, and know the http/ftp adress.

But i need to upload the file via POST (for certain purposes), 
url is something like http://myserver.de/directory

Is that even possible? Because there is no php script whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can not speak HTTP with an FTP Service. Still though you may speak HTTP to the HTTP Service on the same Machine (or server if you will).

You may consider using [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) for this purpose, which basically enables you to put files on a server. 
If your HTTP server is Apache, you may want to start with [this article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html).